# how to use argument to refer partial file name?

Tags: octobercms, partial

I have the following partial file structure:

```
dashboard
  --forrced_popup_form
     --client_type.htm
  --forced_popup_modal.htm
```

Now I am calling partial from admin.htm layout as follows:

```
{% partial 'dashboard/forced_popup_modal' popupFor = 'client_type' %}
```

And I want to include `client_type.htm` partial from `forced_popup_modal.htm` as follows:

```
{% partial 'dashboard/forced_popup_form/'+{{popupFor}} %}
```

I am getting an error. May be I am trying to pass partial file name in bad way. The following line is working fine:

```
{% partial 'dashboard/forced_popup_form/client_type' %}
```

How can I set file name from a variable? I want to replace 'client_type' by a variable passed to this partial.

Answer (score 1):

The following simple line solve my problem:

```
 {% partial 'dashboard/forced_popup_form/'~popupFor %}
```